# How to display image in pictureedit and picturebox when clicked in gridview devexpress in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, picturebox

I want to display images in picturedit and picturebox when I click on gridview devexpress.
I want to display the image when the cell value clicked in the path1 column and path2 column in one pictureedit and one picturebox.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
    Dim Path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\PRODUCT.mdb"
    Dim cn = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path
    Private Images As Hashtable = New Hashtable()

    Private Sub LoadDataGridView()
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select Code,Path1,Path2 FROM ITEM"

            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadDataGridView()
    End Sub

     Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
        Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim path1 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Path1").ToString
        Dim path2 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Path2").ToString
        PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path1)), True, False)
        PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path2)), True, False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[Capturegridview18022022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2FSp.jpg)

[Captureerror18022022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFIam.jpg)

Comment: `SomePictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path1)), true, false)`

Comment: @Jimi , Thanks to replies from you, your code runs perfectly, what if I only use one pictureedit for the path1 & path2 column and appears when I click cell in path1 and path2

Comment: Then you need to use an event that is related to a Cell, not the entire Row

Comment: @Jimi  `Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
        Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim path1 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Path1").ToString
        Dim path2 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Path2").ToString
        PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path1)), True, False)
        PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path2)), True, False)
    End Sub`

Comment: @Jimi , My code is like that but it hasn't worked.

Comment: `RowCellClickEventArgs` gives you the `CellValue`. Isn't that what you need to show the image specified in the current Column of that Row? Why are you using `GetFocusedRowCellValue()` to get the value of both `Path1` and `Path2` Columns? -- Don't post your code in comments, update the question instead. You can click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71167579/edit) link to add more details. Move your code there and delete the comment.

Comment: @Jimi,  yes I need to display an image when clicked cellvalue.

Comment: @Jimi, I have updated the code and there is an error and I also attach screenshot of the error

Comment: You're calling an event as it was a method. Use the `RowCellClickEventArgs` object (represented by `e`) to get the current Cell Value (or call `GetFocusedRowCellValue()`, as you prefer)-- Then you're assigning two different images to the same `PictureEdit1` Control.

Comment: @Jimi , I've done according to you.but only appear images from the path1 column only

Comment: Perhaps because you always use something like `.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Path1")` no matter what the current Cell is? -- I cannot write a tutorial in comments. Try to put in code what has been described here so far. You'll get there.

Comment: @Jimi , I've been successful and the first answer of your code please make as an answer so that I mark the solution on your behalf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.RowCellClick

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
If e.Column.FieldName = "Path1" Then
            Dim path1 As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
            PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path1)), True, False)
        Else
            If e.Column.FieldName = "Path2" Then
                Dim path2 As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
                PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path2)), True, False)
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use Click event instead of RowCellClick

```
Private Sub GridView1_Click(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.Click
    Dim path1 As String = (GridView1.GetRowCellValue(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle,"Path1"))
    Dim path2 As String = (GridView1.GetRowCellValue(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle,"Path2"))
    PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path1)), True, False)
    PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path2)), True, False)
End Sub
```